# Cannot de-stringify an object in Backbone View

Tags: javascript, object, backbone.js, stringify

I do have this stringified object returning from MYSQL

```
"[{"x":278,"y":160},{"x":671,"y":79}]"
```

When I console.log it from my Backbone Model in the view the ouput is

```
[{"x":278,"y":160},{"x":671,"y":79}]
```

When I do this in the console

```
obj = [{"x":278,"y":160},{"x":671,"y":79}]
```

the string is perfectly parsed to an object, but when I do the same thing in my code, I can't access the object.

I tried to JSON.parse, then I get

```
syntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe it's about those unescaped quotes?

Comment: How are you parsing it?

Comment: Check [`typeof obj`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). It may already be parsed to an `Object`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Good point, because if so it would be passed through `toString` as part of `JSON.parse`, and the string would be `[object Array]`. So that `o` would indeed be a JSON syntax error.

Comment: *"I tried to JSON.parse"* Then **quote** your `JSON.parse` code, so we can help you with it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: `points = JSON.parse(this.model.get('points'));`. Another thing I just realized: `this.points = this.model.get('points');` in console log returns `[{"x":150,"y":120},{"x":773,"y":321}]` while `console.log(this.points[0])` returns `[`

Comment: @lunacafu: What does `console.log(typeof this.model.get('points'));` log?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder:it returns string

Comment: @lunacafu: Then your `JSON.parse` line should work, and something is going on that isn't covered by the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with moving the JSON.parse(this.points) from the initializing block of the view. This makes sense, since the data trying to parse obviously was not ready. Should have figured it sooner, since simulating the code in console step by step worked, which usually is indicating this. Thanks @ T.J. Crowder for your effort